# Perl: infinite loop array?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I need an infinite loop into finite array...

Example:

```
@name = ('John', 'Helen', 'Dave');

1=John
2=Helen
3=Dave 
4=John
5=Helen
6=Dave 
7=John
8=Helen
9=Dave 
...etc
```

Is it possible? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, I need an "infinite loop" and know, for example, the name for the 7' day or the name for the 125' day. Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Arrays take memory.  Memory is not infinite.

Comment: Please update your question with what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as if you need to index the finite array with the index number modulo the size of the array:

```
foreach my $i (1..100) { printf "%d=%s\n", $i, $name[$i % scalar(@name)]; }

my @dow = ( 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' );
print $dow[7 % scalar(@dow)], "\n";
print $dow[125 % scalar(@dow)], "\n";
```

Etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why anyone would want to do that, but this will do what you want:

```
my $i=0;
my $cnt=1;
my @name = ('John', 'Helen', 'Dave');

    while($i<scalar (@name )){

        print $cnt."".$name[$i];
        $i++;
        $cnt++;
        $i=$i==scalar(@name)?0:$i;


}
```

Comment: `$c++;` should be `$cnt++;`.

Comment: had to plus this because it was utterly amusing.  =D

Answer (score 1):

For fun, this presents an "infinitely" large array of repeating values (while only storing one copy of each value).

```
use InfinitelyLoopingArray qw( );

tie my @dow_lookup, InfinitelyLoopingArray::,
   qw( Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat );

printf "%3d %s\n", $_, $dow_lookup[$_]
   for 0..9, 125;
```

Where `InfinitelyLoopingArray.pm` contains:

```
package InfinitelyLoopingArray;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw( croak );

sub TIEARRAY {
   my $class = shift;
   return bless([ @_ ], $class);
}

sub FETCHSIZE {
   # Largest supported array index.
   # Currently 2**31-1 or 2**63-1 depending on the build.
   return unpack('J', pack('j', -1)) >> 1;
}

sub FETCH {
   my ($self, $idx) = @_;
   croak "Negative indexes not supported" if $idx < 0;
   return $self->[$idx % @$self];
}

sub new {
   tie my @array, @_;
   return \@array;
}

1;
```

Answer (score 0):

many answers - so one more

```
my(@names) = ('John', 'Helen', 'Dave');
my $cnt;
while(1) {
    print ++$cnt, "=$_\n" for (@names);
}
```

hope, this is enough infinite... :) /at least while the $cnt is overlfow/